# Updating Page Title Based on URL

Tags: php, html

Let's say the `<title>` of `example.com` is `example`

How to automatically update the page title for `example.com/#city1` to `example city1` and `example.com/#city2` to `example city2` and so on.

I have only an `index.html` file and I don't want to add `php` file to my html file so please help me with a simple and clean code.

Comment: Have you configured your server to execute PHP code in .html files? And I assume you're talking about the HTML title? In other words '<title>' and not the title you display in your page. Remember that the '<title>' is not necessarily visible to the user.

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: Yes KIKO, i mean <title>

Comment: with out php  or other scripting langauge its not possible i think

Comment: JavaScript is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dynamic solution, that will update the page title everytime the anchor/hash changes:

```
$(function(){
  // event
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    let hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
    document.title = 'example ' + hash;
  });

  // just to set on page load (you might need to tweak in case there is no hash)
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: Got a syntax error for this line: `let hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );`

Comment: @Smith Try changing `let` to `var`

Comment: The syntax fixed, but still title not change, Am i doing it right:  `<HTML><HEAD><script>
$(function(){
  // event
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
    document.title = 'example ' + hash;
  });

  // just to set on page load (you might need to tweak in case there is no hash)
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});</script>
<TITLE>example</TITLE></HEAD><BODY></body></HTML>`

Comment: @Smith you need to add an anchor on the url `#test1`

Comment: Note that this method requires the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use atleast javascript.

Try this:

```js
var str = 'example.com/#city1';
var str1 = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('.'))+' '+str.substring((0,str.indexOf('#')+1));
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = str1;
//in your case replace p with title tag
```

```html
<p>Change Me</p>
```

Comment: `document.title =str.substring(0,str.indexOf('.'))+' '+str.substring((0,str.indexOf('#')+1))` to change html title